# How to get public and private key from CNG (BCrypt) RSA algorithm?

Tags: c++, winapi, rsa, public-key-encryption, cng

I am kind of stuck, I want to generate new pair of public and private keys.
But I can't find a way to extract them.

I used this: (C++)

```
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg,
                                         BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
                                         NULL,
                                         0);

    if (status) {}

    status = BCryptGenerateKeyPair(hAlg, &hKey, 1024, 0);

    if (status) {}

    status = BCryptFinalizeKeyPair(&hKey, 0);

    if (status) {}
```

(dont mind the status, ill check it later :-) )
but now I want to extract the pair of keys, cant find an example or matching function
I might do something wrong, but what?

Comment: possibly with BCryptExportKey

Comment: @user253751 export it to? I have tried it but then how can i see the key value?

Comment: BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

"export it to?"
[BCryptExportKey function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptexportkey)exports a key to a memory BLOB that can be persisted for later use.

And then you could use [the BCryptImportKeyPair function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptimportkeypair) imports a public/private key pair from a key BLOB.